# Similar-word search in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some javascript which allows you to search text with one word, such as "retrofit" and have it automatically search for other terms such as "renovation", "renovate", "retrofitting", "revamp", "revamping", "modification", "alteration" as well as "retrofit".

For example, in javascript you could define the "other terms" to accompany a word

If the search string equals any word in the word-series, then replace the search string with the word-series and search for all of the words or phrases individually at the same time and return all results

My pseudocode way of doing it:

```
ifInString searchBox, "retrofit" or "renovation" or "renovate" or "retrofitting" or "revamp" or "revamping" or "modification" or "alteration" 
THEN replaceString searchBox with "retrofit, renovation, renovate, retrofitting, revamp, revamping, modification, alteration" 
THEN find any words delimeted by commas
```

Comment: Why pseudo-code? Can you post your JavaScript code?

Comment: I don't have javascript code to do this, I'm looking for javascript code that does this